# ¿Por qué algo que "está tirado" es algo "fácil"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, coloquialismos, españa

No es raro oír en España trozos de conversación del tipo:

> ¡El examen **estaba tirado**! Estoy convencido de que sacaré un diez.

o

> [Bah](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4mX1tFr), deja de preocuparte por la ruta: llegar a Murcia **está tirado** si sigues la autopista del Mediterráneo.

Es decir, en ambos casos *estar tirado* denota que algo es muy fácil, que no requiere esfuerzo alguno.

En efecto, el DRAE recoge:

> [**tirado, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZqS1ueI)
>   Del part. de *tirar*.
>   1. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Que se da muy barata o es de fácil realización u obtención.

Sin embargo, no explica de dónde viene ni cómo se llegó hasta aquí. ¿Alguien lo sabe? ¿Se usa también en Hispanoamérica?

Comment: Interesante! Ojalá supiera de dónde viene. Lo que sí en Chile se usa y mucho. Se acostumbra también a decir *chancho tirado* o como coloquialmente se usa *chancho tira'o*. Me sorprende que se use con la misma connotación en España. Pensé que era diferente.

Comment: A: "El Jorge habla tres idiomas, y todos muy, muy bien." B: "Sí, es bárbaro."  A veces se usa una palabra con significado contrario para dar un gran efecto.

Comment: @aparente001 muy buena observación que me ha despertado la duda. Consultado en [¿Cómo pasó “bárbaro” a tener una connotación positiva?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20592/1674)

Answer (score 4):

Pues me he encontrado con una cosa muy curiosa, y es que según el NTLLE, la expresión "estar tirado" ha cambiado completamente de significado a lo largo del tiempo. Fíjate:

> Andar alguna cosa mui *tirada*. Phrase, que vale no hallarse, ò haber carestia de ella.

El *Diccionario de Autoridades* definía la expresión como usada para cuando era muy difícil encontrar alguna cosa dada su escasez. En 1852 esta expresión desaparece del diccionario, y en 1925 aparece la siguiente:

> TIRADO, DA. Dícese de las cosas que se dan muy baratas o de aquellas que abundan mucho y se encuentran fácilmente.

Ahora la expresión pasa a significar todo lo contrario: cuando algo *está tirado* lo que te están diciendo es que es tan fácil de encontrar y conseguir como si te lo encontraras tirado por el suelo en cualquier parte. Fíjate que en esta acepción ya se menciona la palabra "fácilmente".

> *Te pones a ver y el cine aquí está tirado. A cinco pelas hoy en una sala del centro.*
>
> Miguel Delibes, "Diario de un emigrante", 1958 (España).

De esta "facilidad" para encontrar algo se pasó a la "facilidad" para hacer cualquier cosa, como ya lo atestigua la edición manual de 1985:

> **estar** una cosa **tirada** o **muy tirada**, fr. que se aplica a lo que se hace sin dificultad o es fácil de aprender o comprender.

Comment: ¡Qué cosa tan curiosa! Pensé que estaba tirado saber su origen, pero veo que está tirado... en su significado original :D