# ¿Cómo pasó "bárbaro" a tener una connotación positiva?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, adjetivos

Cuando miramos la definición de *bárbaro* observamos unas primeras acepciones con carácter negativo:

> [**bárbaro, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=52DLHf1)
>   Del lat. barbărus, y este del gr. βάρβαρος bárbaros 'extranjero', voz de or. onomat., a partir del sonido *bar*.
>   1. adj. Dicho de una persona: De alguno de los pueblos que desde el siglo V invadieron el Imperio romano y se fueron extendiendo por la mayor parte de Europa. U. t. c. s.
>   2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a los bárbaros.
>   3. adj. Fiero, cruel. *Su bárbaro vecino lo golpeó*.

Pero poco a poco va cogiendo un cariz positivo, fantástico:

> 4. adj. Arrojado, temerario. U. t. c. s. *El corredor alcanzó los 200 km por hora; es un bárbaro*.
>   5. adj. Inculto, grosero, tosco. Su estilo es descuidado y un tanto bárbaro.
>   6. adj. Grande, excesivo, extraordinario. *Le hizo un desplante bárbaro*.
>   7. adj. Excelente, llamativo, magnífico. *El orador estuvo bárbaro*.

Si nos centramos en Hispanoamérica, el diccionario de americanismos recoge un montón de acepciones positivas al respecto:

> [**bárbaro, -a**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=KKAP3PaOtx0AUkspQgK%7CjAkhw4fU6x0A7gh3Jtf)
>   I.  1.  sust/adj. Gu, Ho, Ni, Pa, Cu, RD, PR, Ve, Ec, Bo. Persona experimentada, ágil y diestra en un oficio o para realizar una determinada actividad. [pop + cult → espon](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20572/1674).
>   2.  adj. Ec, Ar, Ur. Referido a persona, comprensiva, solidaria o de trato agradable. pop.

Además de *¡bárbaro!* como interjección de asombro o acuerdo.

Mirando en el [mapa de diccionarios académicos](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) veo que acepciones como *adj.Grande, excesivo, extraordinario.* no estaban en 1925 y se añadieron en 1992. Y lo mismo ocurre con *adj.Excelente, llamativo, magnífico*.

Por todo ello, me pregunto: ¿cómo tomó esta acepción positiva la palabra *bárbaro*?

Comment: Concretamente, en 1970 se añadió a "barbaridad" la acepción de "cantidad grande o excesiva", y en 1983 se añadieron a bárbaro las acepciones de "grande, excesivo" y la de interjección de asombro o extrañeza.

Comment: Básicamente porque porque los europeos llamaban barbaros a los habitantes originarios y barbaridad a sus usos y costumbres; La gran dicotomía entre la civilización y la barbarie del "Facundo" de Sarmiento.
Los "salvajes" simplemente aprendieron a asociar las exclamaciones de barbarie con su propia cultura y valores positivos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*No vale como respuesta porque no sé cómo pasó a ser un concepto positivo, pero aporto un poquito de contexto:*

*Bárbaro* no es la única palabra de significado negativo que luego se usa con valor positivo. Aquí algunos ejemplos:

> **[soberbio, bia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Y4X46Ep)**
>
> 3. adj. Grandioso, magnífico.
>
> **[monstruo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PiY3lWL)**
>
> 6. m. Persona que en cualquier actividad excede en mucho las cualidades y aptitudes comunes.
>
> ¡**[bestia](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=bestia)**!
>
> 1. interj. Ec. Expresa gran admiración.
>
> **[mortal](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=mortal)**
>
> 1. adj. Ni, Cu, Bo, Py; Ch, cult → espon; Ur, p.u. Referido a cosa, excelente, muy buena. pop.
> 2. Cu. Referido a persona, simpática, comprensiva y servicial.

La figura retórica se llama **[antífrasis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%ADfrasis)**, y la aporta Rafael en su respuesta al [uso de figurado de la palabra *menudo*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16995/6915). Hay algo en la ensalada simbólica de nuestra cultura y de nuestro lenguaje que nos lleva a entender (sin que nos lo expliquen) que a veces algunas cosas (palabras, gestos, objetos...) significan lo contrario del significado literal.

Yo creo (si se me permite) que en estos casos hay un ejercicio de empatía. Para los que están dentro de las fronteras siendo asediados, por cierto que los bárbaros son crueles y toscos, portadores de muerte, enfermedad, pecado y mugre. Pero los que están afuera, venciendo, la están pasando bárbaro. Quién no quisiera estar en los festines de Olaf el Vikingo o en la aldea gala de Astérix.

Answer (score 4):

Puede ser algo complicado de ver, pero voy a dar una respuesta tentativa a ver qué te parece.

Como hemos visto, la voz *barbaridad* pasó antes que la voz *bárbaro* a tener esa connotación de "cantidad grande o excesiva". Anteriormente significaba simplemente "calidad de bárbaro", teniendo *bárbaro* entre otras acepciones la de "inculto, grosero, tosco".

Por tanto, se usaba en contextos como este (negritas mías):

> *Los malsines acompañaron al de Leyva y le confesaron que doña Elvira los había comisionado para que lo cosiesen a puñaladas, pero que ellos no tenían entrañas para hacer **tamaña barbaridad** con tan rumboso mancebo.*
>
> Ricardo Palma, "Tradiciones peruanas, cuarta serie", 1877 (Perú).

Y ahí creo que yo que está el quid de la cuestión. El término *barbaridad* se podía "medir", clasificando las barbaridades como más o menos grandes:

> *Llenóse de horror de **tan grande barbaridad**, y se volvió a su casa mudo de palabras y frío del corazón pareciéndole que el cielo y la tierra se habían mudado.*
>
> Braulio Foz, "Vida de Pedro Saputo", 1844 (España).

Esta peculiaridad, unido a que *barbaridad* es una palabra ya de por sí con un toque hiperbólico, hicieron que una "barbaridad" denotase simplemente a algo exagerado:

> *Hollywood existe y es una ciudad como otra cualquiera, más "escenario" que otra cualquiera, menos íntima que cualquier ciudad, pero existe. Toma si existe y menudas inundaciones acabamos de padecer. ¡**Qué barbaridad**; qué manera de caer agua!*
>
> Charles Film, "Complementos [Radio y Cinema, 1938]", 1938 (España).

Y en la jerga juvenil:

> *[...] me veía obligado a imprimir las sandeces de aquella presuntuosa irresponsable, redactadas en un estilo de criada. Escribía "es más fácil imaginarlo que describirlo, bello como de película, feo como no sé qué cosa, me divierto **una barbaridad**, es imposible poder...".*
>
> Pitigrilli, "El estilo criada [La Codorniz, 24 de julio de 1966]", 1966 (España).

Y en Hispanoamérica:

> *Claro que tendremos que prender espirales, porque ha de haber **barbaridad de** mosquitos...*
>
> Juan Bautista Rivarola Matto, "Yvypóra", 1970 (Paraguay).

Este cambio en el significado de *barbaridad* también lo tuvo la voz *bárbaro*:

> *Allí se me ocurrió un plan **bárbaro**, que si contaba yo con Isabel y con la tía Clara sería la felicidad absoluta.*
>
> Rafael Sánchez Mazas, "La vida nueva de Pedrito de Andía", 1956 (España).

Aunque tal vez en menor medida y por eso entró más tarde en el diccionario. En este último caso se podría pensar que "bárbaro" tiene la acepción original negativa (un plan que solo se le ocurriría a un bárbaro), pero se interpreta también como positivo, dado que el tono del escritor es de aprobación, como dando a entender que los hechos descritos son buenos.

Por último, también pudo venir el cambio de significado por la inclusión de la voz en frases como "pasarlo como un bárbaro":

> *—Estas desgracias repentinas le sobrecogen al más templado —dijo el pastor—; y mayormente cuando te caen en día de fiesta, que no se trae más que descuido y alegría y pensamiento de pasarlo chachi-**bárbaro**, como ellos dicen; así que te hace el efecto de caer de repente de lo blanco a lo negro.*
>
> Rafael Sánchez Ferlosio, "El Jarama", 1956 (España).